# Flutter images memory does not get gc

Tags: image, flutter, memory-leaks

I have a page widget to display a long list of images using Image.network() on android device. After a long scroll and gets every image displayed, the memory has gone up quite a lot to 200MB. The app is working fine atm and then I leave the page, dispose() called. The memory usage, however, is still not reduced.

[image]

as you can see from the graph, the external memory is occupying 186MB of space and never goes down. I read the devTool doc that external memory is native objects. But why aren't they garbage collected? Or maybe that is just the android way of managing memory?

Please check below my sample code. I'm placing it at the tabbarviews, when I select another tab, the page get disposed.

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  List<Product> products = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("initState");
    fetchProducts();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("dispose");
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future fetchProducts() async {
    //get the list of products
    setState(() {
      products = ...;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: products.length,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
              childAspectRatio: 0.8),
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            final product = products[position];
            final imageData = product.mainImage;
            if (imageData != null && imageData.downloadURL != null) {
              return Image.network(
                imageData.downloadURL,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              );
            } else {
              return Image.asset("assets/images/product_image_placeholder.jpg");
            }
          }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i think you should clean image cache

Comment: @veneno could you please put up your example code?

Comment: `PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear();` try it before dispose

Comment: @veneno it works! thank you, Sir. I have one more question, is it safe to just leave the memory cache like it is and let it manage itself? I have not idea how memory management works underneath in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Image widget retains cached images and does not release the memory under certain circumstances. That's a [known](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60160)  [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62107) and as of Nov 2, 2020 is still opened.

You can check it with DevTools Profiling if you look at the `_Int64List` variable. It's growing when you update your image with new instances.

[image]

As a workaround for now we're manually clearing the cache on every `build()` and on `dispose()`:

```
 PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear();
 PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clearLiveImages();
```

Comment: Unfortunately your workaround is not fixing the issue.